# My RPi won't update

Tags: apt, update, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, 64-bit

Raspberry Pi 4b 8gb ram 64x bullseye[image]

```
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y
[sudo] password for luqman: 
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                
Hit:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye InRelease                                                                                                                                                                       
Ign:6 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                      
Err:7 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.21 80]
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                   
Err:10 https://mirror.mwt.me/ghd/deb any InRelease                                                                                            
  410  Gone [IP: 172.67.71.39 443]
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease
Hit:9 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian stretch Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.mwt.me/ghd/deb/dists/any/InRelease  410  Gone [IP: 172.67.71.39 443]
E: The repository 'https://mirror.mwt.me/ghd/deb any InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

Comment: Time to upgrade your distribution. Debian Stretch is badly outdated: https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/

Comment: a mix of bullseye and stretch repos? I'm sure your pi is rock solid stable

Answer (score 1):

Partially because there are no more updates for *stretch*; actual software version updating stopped in 2020, as did normal security updates, and LTS updating ended last year.

- https://wiki.debian.org/LTS
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Release_table

Note that the reason stretch is highlighted with the yellow "older, still maintained" in the wikipedia article is because of [Freexian](https://www.freexian.com/lts/extended/docs/how-to-use-extended-lts/), which uses its own repositories.

> Extended long-term support (ELTS) provided by Freexian but made available to all Debian users, as noted on official Debian pages. There is no kernel support, and only sponsored packages are supported.

And that is because you did something wacky with stuff in `/etc/apt/sources`, or else the card was used in an older Pi before this.

Remove or comment out everything in `/etc/apt/sources.list` except the "bullseye" lines and try using `dist-upgrade` instead of `full-upgrade`.

Comment: That file looks like this: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
# Uncomment deb-src lines below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

Comment: You should edit that information into your question, and explain where the SD card came from (or how the stuff in "sources" got that way).